CesiumJS - click on terrain and see elevation value
Just wondering if anyone could advise me if its possible to click on the terrain in cesium and get the elevation value for that point? I've uploaded a raster terrain (geotiff) which has been created in cesium ion as terrain on the globe.

definitely possible. did you try viewer.scene.globe.getHeight?
